# Define/store individual elements of Table output for back-substitution

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, variable-definitions, iteration

At its core, mine is a very simple communication error between me and Mathematica that I haven't been able to crack, so I do apologise if it seems embarassingly inane.

Please consider the following simplified set-up. I have x[-1] and I seek an expression for x[5] using Table:

`root = Table[Solve[2x[b]+x[b-1]+b == 0, x[b]] /.x[-1]->1, {b,0,5}]`

The output:

`{{{x[0]->-(1/2)}}, {{x[1] -> 1/2 (-1 - x[0])}}, {{x[2] -> 1/2 (-2 - x[1])}},`

`{{x[3] -> 1/2 (-3 - x[2])}}, {{x[4] -> 1/2 (-4 - x[3])}},`

`{{x[5] -> 1/2 (-5 - x[4])}}}`.

(I don't have the right lingo for this, but) the output elements don't *engage* like numbers. If I were to try something like
`root[[1]]+1`,

I would get

`{{1 + (x[0] -> -(1/2))}}`

(and `Rules->Equal` just changes that `->` to `=`; the behaviour remains the same).

Is it possible to define these `x[b]` such that back-substitution happens *while* Table is at work? If not, can you please advise on how to define individual output elements (without directly assigning values from the output to each x[b])?

As an aside, is it better Mathematica practice to abandon this whole Table business and use a loop instead?

So many thanks in advance!

--PhysicsHobbit

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a task for [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html):

```
ClearAll[x, b]
RecurrenceTable[{2 x[b] + x[b - 1] + b == 0, x[-1] == 1}, x, {b, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> {-(1/2), -(1/4), -(7/8), -(17/16), -(47/32), -(113/64)}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html):

```
ClearAll[func]
func = x /. RSolve[{2 x[b] + x[b - 1] + b == 0, x[-1] == 1}, x, b][[1]];

func /@ Range[0, 5]
```

> ```
>  {-(1/2), -(1/4), -(7/8), -(17/16), -(47/32), -(113/64)}
> ```

If you *have to* use `Table` + `Solve` you can do

```
roots = Flatten @ Table[Solve[2 x[b] + x[b - 1] + b == 0, x[b]] /. x[-1] -> 1, 
  {b, 0,  5}]; 
Fold[# /. #2 &, roots[[All, 2]], Reverse[roots]]
```

> ```
>  {-(1/2), -(1/4), -(7/8), -(17/16), -(47/32), -(113/64)}
> ```